# Color columns of a HTML out put through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySql table like this

```
client_id       client_name     inrement
  123         Jhon          5
  555         Smith        10
  666         Aron             15
  777         Herath           2
  888         Jaya             1
  999         RRR              20
```

And I 'm using the following code to get this table information to a HTML table

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("offlinesurv", $con);


 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM increments ");

echo "<table border='3' BORDERCOLOR=BLUE align='center' >
<tr>
<th>Client-id</th>
 <th>Client-Name</th>
 <th>Incre</th>
 </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['client_id'] ."</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] ."</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['inrement'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My out out is like below

```
client_id       client_name     inrement
  123             Jhon             5
  555             Smith            10
  666             Aron             15
  777             Herath           2
  888             Jaya             1
  999             RRR              20
```

My problem is that I need to color in red the rows in the Output report(HTML table)  where increment is greater than 10 only (increment>10). Could someone please help me on doing this. Can I do it from PHP? AJAX? if so please help me on this becoz I'm new in to both

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $class = $row['inrement']>10?'red':'normal';
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class=\"$class\">" . $row['client_id'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"$class\">" . $row['client_name'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"$class\">" . $row['inrement'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then set your CSS to handle the two classes (you can name them whatever you like - I just called them `red` and `normal` for clarity):

```
<style>
.red{
    color: #ff0000;
}
.normal{
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if else block` like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   if($row['inrement'] > 10) {
   echo "<tr style='color:red;'>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['client_id'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['inrement'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
   else {
  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['client_id'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['inrement'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
echo "<table border='3' BORDERCOLOR=BLUE align='center' >
<tr>
<th>Client-id</th>
 <th>Client-Name</th>
 <th>Incre</th>
 </tr>";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
  if($i>1){
    echo "<tr style='background:red'>";
  }else{
    echo "<tr>";
  }
 echo "<td>" . 1 ."</td>";
 echo "<td>" . 2 ."</td>";
 echo "<td>" . 3 . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
?>
```

This is one example implementing your requirement.You can apply the logic in your code.